# Removing Gulp CLI version 3.91 from Mac

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to uninstall gulp 3.9.1 from my mac globally so I can install version 4 globally.

I do the following:

```
npm uninstall -g gulp;
gulp -v
```

And see that it is still installed:

`CLI version 3.9.1`

How do I located the issue and remove totally?